# Como ordenar os registros corretamente usando o DISTINCT

Tags: sqlite

Em minha tabela tenho a coluna `DESCRICAO` e a `DATA_DE_CADASTRO` dos itens. Em minha aplicação no Android gostaria de exibir os últimos 10 registros que foram gravados.

Há uma série de atributos que devem ser informados ao gravar um novo item, portanto essa listagem serve para que ele, caso queira, escolha um item a partir do qual poderá copiar alguns atributos para o outro item que ele esta gravando no momento já que ambos os itens compartilham das mesmas informações.

Desse modo gostaria de ter os 10 últimos registros distintamente por que não faz sentido, nesse caso, apresentar-lhe uma lista com 10 itens repetidos.

Faço select ordenando-o pela coluna DTCAD de modo decrescente.

```
SELECT DSBEM FROM TAB ORDER BY DTCAD DESC
```

E ele me traz os seguintes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta certo. `TELEFONE DIGITAL COM VISOR` foi o último item a ser gravado,  porém temos vários itens repetidos, mas se faço o select

```
SELECT DISTINCT DSBEM FROM TAB ORDER BY DTCAD DESC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora esta errado. Cadê o telefone digital?

Já criei os índice para a descrição para a dtcad, para a descrição e dtcad.

O comando

```
SELECT DISTINCT DSBEM FROM ( 
SELECT DSBEM FROM TAB ORDER BY DTCAD desc ) LIMIT 10
```

também não funciona.

O que poderia ser feito?

Uma possível solução seria essa query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DTCAD, DSBEM FROM TAB order by datetime(DTCAD) desc
```

mas o retorno é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muda para ficar assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DTCAD, DSBEM FROM TAB ORDER BY DTCAD DESC
```

O que está acontecendo é que quando você coloca o distinct por denominação o telefone que está repetido some porque você não considera também a data de cadastro como fator diferenciador. Esse ajuste vai considerar como fator de unicidade denominação E data, fazendo assim que o registro do telefone volte a aparecer.

Comment: Tive de alterar a sua query. Ficou algo assim: `SELECT DISTINCT DTCAD, DSBEM FROM TAB ORDER BY DTCAD DESC` Era isso que você pretendia. Não é?

Comment: Mas mesmo assim não funciona. De fato, eu já havia tentado isso. A query devolve linhas da descrição repetidas porque houve alteração na data de cadastro e desse modo passa pelo crivo do DISTINCT.

Comment: Estranho demais. Faz o seguinte, manda o DER dessa tabela do banco. Coloca na pergunta a imagem,

Comment: Eu criei uma tabela simples, com duas colunas: `CREATE TABLE TAB (
    DSBEM VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    DTCAD DATETIME
);` com um select na tabela principal e ocorre a mesma questão.

Comment: Testa usando: order by datetime(DTCAD) desc

Comment: Acontece a mesma coisa. As linhas da descrição se repetem porque houve alteração na coluna DTCAD.

Comment: Postei o resultado dessa query na pergunta.

Comment: Pronto, faz assim agora: select distinct DSBEM from (SELECT DISTINCT DTCAD, DSBEM FROM TAB order by datetime(DTCAD) desc).

Comment: Legal assim mesmo: `SELECT DISTINCT DSBEM FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DTCAD, DSBEM FROM TBL795 ORDER bY DTCAD DESC) LIMIT 10` funcionou.